# How to await Map<int,Future<T>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've a `Map<int, Future<GpxCoordinates>>` in which the `int` key is the id of the entity and the future contains the async call to my API to get data for the related entity id.

I need to start all the requests togethers and then await them.

That's my not working implementation:

```dart
try {
      Map<int, Future<GpxCoordinates>> gpxsCoordinatesToFetch = {};

      for (var tourId in event.toursIds) {
        gpxsCoordinatesToFetch[tourId] = gpxRepository.fetchGpxCoordinates(tourId);
      }

      // Problem in the return await type
      final gpxsCoordinates = await Future.wait(gpxsCoordinatesToFetch.values);

      emit(GpxsCoordinatesLoaded(coordinates: gpxsCoordinates));
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      emit(GpxError());
    }
```

The problem is that the `Future.await` returns a `List<GpxCoordinates>` but I need to return a `Map<int, GpxCoordinates>`. Does it exists a way to obtain the desired `Map<int, GpxCoordinates>` once all requests have been finished?

Comment: What are the int?  Just the index numbers?  Or arbitrary int like 12345, 67, 890?

Comment: In this case they are database unique ids of related entities

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow connect the received data with the id. This is one of the ways to achieve it:

```
try {
  final Map<int, String> values = {};
  final List<Future> futures = [];
  for (var tourId in [1, 2]) {
    futures.add(Future.microtask(() async {
      // Do the call here
      final String value = await Future.value('some value');

      values[tourId] = value;
    }));
  }

  await Future.wait(futures);

  print(values);
} catch (e) {
  // ...
}
```

Outputs:
`{1: some value, 2: some value}`

Another one (probably better):

```
...
for (var tourId in [1, 2]) {
  futures.add(
    Future.value('some value').then((value) => values[tourId] = value),
  );
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  // Problem in the return await type
  final gpxsCoordinates = await Future.wait(gpxsCoordinatesToFetch.values);
```

with

```
Map<int,GpxCoordinates> gpxsCoordinates = {};
for (final mapEntry in gpxsCoordinatesToFetch.entries) {
   final key = mapEntry.key;
   final futureVal = mapEntry.value;
   gpxsCoordinates[key] = await futureVal;
}
```

**Edit:**
You can await map at once by using third party libraries or creating a function that does that.
Above example could be re-written as

```
...
Map<int,GpxCoordinates> gpxsCoordinates = await awaitMap<int,GpxCoordinates>(gpxVal);
...
```

Helper function.

```
Future<Map<R,S>> awaitMap<R,S>(Map<R,Future<S>> myMap) async {
  Map<R, S> res = {};
  for (final mapEntry in myMap.entries) {
    final key = mapEntry.key;
    final val = mapEntry.value;
    res[key] = await val;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: In this way I simply execute all futures one by one, I want to await all of them togheters.

Comment: I have simplified the answer, as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
final gpxsCoordinatesList = await Future.wait(
  gpxsCoordinatesToFetch.entries.map((e) {
    return (() async => {e.key: await e.value})();
  }),
);
final gpxsCoordinates = {
  for (final e in gpxsCoordinatesList) e.keys.first: e.values.first
};
```

it may look a bit confusing but, we're just mapping each entry of **`<int, Future<GpxCoordinates>>`** to a function that returns a **`Future<int, GpxCoordinates>`** and calling that function.

then change the `List<Map<int, GpxCoordinates>>` to just a `Map<int, GpxCoordinates>`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`Map.fromIterables`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterables.html) with [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html) to implement a version of the [`Iterable<Future<T>>.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/FutureIterable/wait.html) extension that instead operates on `Map`s, converting a `Map<K, <Future<V>>` to a `Map<K, V>`:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

extension FutureMap<K, V> on Map<K, Future<V>> {
  /// Converts a `Map<K, Future<V>>` to a `Map<K, V>`.
  ///
  /// Like [FutureIterable<T>.wait] but waits on [Map] values.
  Future<Map<K, V>> get wait async {
    // Copy the keys now in case this `Map` is mutated while waiting.
    var keysCopy = [...keys];
    var awaitedValues = await Future.wait(values);
    return Map.fromIterables(keysCopy, awaitedValues);
  }
}

void main() async {
  Future<T> returnLater<T>(T value) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    return value;
  }

  var map = {
    'a': returnLater(1),
    'b': returnLater(2),
    'c': returnLater(3),
    'd': returnLater(4),
    'e': returnLater(5),
  };

  var stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  var result = await map.wait;
  print(stopwatch.elapsed);
  print(result);
}
```

Which prints:

```
0:00:01.003000
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}
```

indicating that all of the `Future`s were awaited in parallel.

Note that the above implementation of `Map<K, Future<V>>.wait` will complete immediately if any of the `Future` values fail and discard additional failures.  I've added [a different version](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartbag/latest/collection/FutureMap/wait.html) to my [`dartbag`](https://pub.dev/packages/dartbag) package with better error-handling to collect all errors.